# How the heck do you generate flutter/dart files from a proto file?

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've tried all kinds of solutions to this but apparently I'm either stupid or the document is horrible.

i.e.:

I've hacked protoc onto my machine on windows, because you know, we're apparently second class citizens.
I've installed the protoc_dart plugin globally. (which I don't have a clue where it put it because I don't have the .pub_cache folder that is referenced everywhere else, but protoc returns help if run directly and magic, so whatever it works as far as that goes.)

I'm in the directory I want the .dart files to be created.  I use any variation of protoc --dart_out="" and it tells me that the file does not reside within any path specified blah blah blah.  The files are in a different folder which I have tried relative to the current folder and with a full path including drive and it doesn't matter.

I've also tried the dotnet x global tool from here https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc-flutter, and it works as far as it goes but then empty is not available etc. because apparently allowing nullable types is magic too that requires more hacking.

So what is the explicit command to call protoc and generate .dart files that actually work including things like empty referenced properly etc with a source directory and a destination? I would have thought this was trivial but apparently it's incredibly hard and magic.

And anyone know why this isn't just a flutter dev tool that just works by calling a command and be done with it? Not sure how Google thinks that this is an acceptable experience for flutter developers wanting to use GRPC but it clearly is not and needs to be fixed yesterday.

Comment: I'm **not** using Windows but I did recently check out gRPC with Dart to help someone else with an issue. See a working example here: https://github.com/DazWilkin/dart-grpc-logger. `protoc` is challenging but there's an example in the `README.md` that may help you understand the structure.

Comment: so using yours I got the same has I had before: protoc --proto_path=D:\Repos\<path>\ --dart_out=plugins=grpc . system.proto

system.proto is absolutely in the directory.  It still returns File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths...

Comment: Because you're specifying `--proto_path=X` you must prefix that path when you specify `system.proto` too... you must duplicate it.... `D:\Repos\<path>\system.proto`. Make sense? It's confusing for sure but it is due to the tool's "challenges" with paths. Please revise your question with more details of you directory structure and location of protos and I'll try to provide the `protoc` command for you